# How to send emails when a new user signs up?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for advice on how to send a welcome email when a new user signs up and when I add new web development challenges to my website.

I don't have any idea how to do that, so I've been doing some research and found that we need to make an API call to the mail service (i.e., Mailgun) when a new user signs up.

Here are some questions for you:

1. Do I need to buy an email address on my custom domain? I already have a custom domain.

2  Which service should I use for this? Meantime, I want to stay away from paying for the email service right now as I have less number of signed-up users.

I'm using GitHub firebase authentication to authenticate the users.

My Tech Stack: ReactJs, Firebase

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://blog.logrocket.com/send-custom-email-templates-firebase-react-express/ and this: https://betterprogramming.pub/dead-simple-auth-with-react-and-firebase-592e40ff43c5

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to send a verification email to the user. I want to send a welcome email. I am using firebase github authentication.